# htaccess? to redirect 2 different sub domains names to separate sites and servers

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a domain with sub domains setup for

wiki.domain.co.uk
owa.domain.co.uk
owncloud.domain.co.uk

The Wiki & Owncloud sit on Apache on a Ubuntu box. The OWA on IIS on a MS Exchange server box. Presently I am directing http to the Ubuntu box and HTTPS to the Exchange box and accessing the sites that way but this can mean entering a long URL to get to the correct location on the Apache server. In addition I would prefer all sites to be accessed using HTTPS.

Presently if I enter any of the above into a URL I go to the default page of the Web server that I am port forwarding to.

My aim would be to have it so that if I goto wiki.domain.co.uk have the traffic divert specifically to the main wiki URL e.g. "wiki.domain.co.uk/wiki/clients/login.php" and the same with the owncloud subdomain. In addition I want to divert the owa.domain.co.uk and "domain.co.uk/owa" to the MSIIS server. If possible my preference would be for them all to use HTTPS although this is not a complete necessity.

I hope I am using the correct terminology and that this makes sense. I believe I need to forward all traffic to the Ubuntu box and setup a .htaccess file to do this but I am unsure as to if this is the correct way of doing this and the settings to set or even if this is achievable.

Any help or guidance much appreciated.

Comment: This should be done through the DNS using a `cname` and not through apache.

Comment: I am unsure how the cname would work as I am not trying to divert from one subdomain to another or anything like that?

Comment: Actually, I think I am wrong. If you are simply trying to point one subdomain to one server and another subdomain to another you want to add two `A` records (one for each server or more if you have more than two subdomains). From there you would use apache to route the domain to the website folder. If this is what you are trying to do let me know and I will post an answer.

Comment: I only have one real I.P address so it all goes to the same router.

Comment: I worked it out I had to have the domains all go to the IIS system and then had to use ARR/URL Rewrite to direct the relevant sub-domains to the Apache server.